# Strategies for "Pre-Warming" an ASP.NET Cache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 / .NET Web Application, which is *heavily* data-driven, mainly around the concept of "Locations" (New York, California, etc).

Anyway, we have some pretty busy database queries, which get cached after they are finished.

E.g:

```
public ICollection<Location> FindXForX(string x)
{
   var result = _cache.Get(x.ToKey()) as Locaiton; // try cache

   if (result == null) {
      result = _repo.Get(x.ToKey()); // call db
      _cache.Add(x.ToKey(), result); // add to cache
   }

   return result;
}
```

But i don't want to the unlucky first user to be waiting for this database call.

The database call can take anywhere from 40-60 seconds, well over the default timeout for an ASP.NET request.

I want to "pre-warm" these calls for certain "popular" locations (e.g New York, California) when my app starts up, or shortly after.

I don't want to simply do this in **Global asax** (Application_Start), because the app will take too long to start up. (i plan to pre-cache around 15 locations, so that's a few minutes of work).

Is there any way i can fire off this logic asynchronously? Maybe a service on the side is a better option?

The only other alternative i can think of is have an **admin page** which has buttons for these actions. So an administrator (e.g me) can fire off these queries once the app has started up. That would be the easiest solution.

Any advice?

Comment: "The database call can take anywhere from 40-60 seconds" - I'm assuming you have appropriate indexes?

Comment: Yup, that seems like a very long query. You should try to make it more efficient - that might even get rid of this pre-warming issue! :)

Comment: @Mitch What - yes, we have indexes. It's as fast as i can be. If we have a query "Find all locations in New York", it needs to find all cities, neighborhoods, streets. Could be 5 million records. One bad query to save 5 million others which are now redundant due to cache. Worth it, trust me - there is a method to the madness. :)

Comment: " It's as fast as i can be" - you sure? how many logical reads?

Comment: @RPM1984: Side note, awesome gravatar!

Comment: @Mitch Wheat - i stand corrected, i thought this view we had was indexed. It wasn't. :( My bad...adding index.

Comment: added as answer below...

Comment: RPM - not sure about your functionality, so this suggestion may be moot. however, as it sounds like there's hierarchical data involved, would it not be a better idea to lazy load the underlying zones/street data if a request targets it?? altho' it's nice to have it ALL loaded up front, there's also a case to be said for targetted caching and targetted querying. i would be tempted to put some stats in place to measure the frequency and depth of queries on the object graph and then look at 'alternative' strategies based on hard facts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would be to fire-off a `Task` from `Application_Start`

But I've found that it's nice to wrap this functionality into a bit of infrastructure so that you can create an ~/Admin/CacheInfo page to let you monitor the progress, state, and exceptions that may be in the process of loading up the cache.

Answer (score 6):

Look into ["Always running"](http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/10/11/iis-7-5-and-always-running-web-applications.aspx) app setting for IIS 7.5. What this basically do is have an app pool ready whenever the existing one is to be recycled. Of course, the very first would take the 40-60 seconds but afterwards things would be fast unless you physically restart the machine.

Answer (score 3):

Before you start cache warming, I suggest you check that the query is "as fast as it can be" by first looking at how many logical reads it is doing.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you should just dump the results in a separate table and have a scheduled task to repopulate that table periodically.

If one pre-calculated table isn't enough because it ends up with too much data that you need to search through, you could use more than one.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to **launch a worker thread in your `Application_Start` method** that does the pre-warming in the background. If you do it right, your app won't take longer to start up, because the thread will be executed asynchronously.

Comment: He said in his question that he didn't want to do this.

Comment: @Shan Plourde - i said i didn't want to *wait* for this in the application_start method, but a worker thread would be fine. At the moment though, im leaning towards my original proposal (an admin page, so i can monitor the cache a little better, manually invalidate items, warm them up, etc).

Comment: Hmm, your statement "I don't want to simply do this in Global asax (Application_Start), because the app will take too long to start up. (i plan to pre-cache around 15 locations, so that's a few minutes of work)." seems to be a bit different from your comment...so yeah, Application_Start would work great

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a website health monitoring service. It can be used to both check website health, and if scheduled frequently enough, to invoke your common URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the loading in a `Task` from `Application_Start` is the way to go, as mentioned by Scott.

Just be careful - if your site restarts and 10 people try to view California, you don't want to end up with 10 instances of `_repo.Get(x.ToKey()); // call db` simultaneously trying to load the same data.

It might be a good idea to store a boolean value `"IsPreloading"` in the application state. Set it to `true` at the start of your preload function and `false` at the end. If the value is set, make sure you don't load any of your 15 preloaded locations in `FindXForX`.

Comment: Double-checked locking can be useful for what you suggest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Microsoft_.NET_.28Visual_Basic.2C_C.23.29

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest taking a look at [auto-starting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) your app, especially if you are load balanced.